# Log4j configuration warnings when calling method from external JAR via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, log4j, invoke

I'm calling a method using reflection. To do this, at runtime, I:

1) Load the JAR file containing the class that declares the method

```
loader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;

Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.setAccessible(true);         
method.invoke(lLoader, new Object[] {lJarFile.toURI().toURL()});
```

2) Call the method

```
lExternalMethod.invoke(lClass.newInstance());
```

3) The method call works and does what its supposed to do, but I get the following in the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (JarName) 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly
```

I don't use log4j in my application, but the JAR I'm loading to call the method does. The method I call has multiple lines:

```
Logger.GetLogger().Log("Msg", "Msg description");
```

Also, the JAR also contains the log4j.properties file.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a Log4J configuration file, or just ignore it--it's a harmless warning saying there's no Log4J configuration file. (Yes, there is, but apparently not one that defines the root appenders etc.) You should only see that message on startup.

Comment: I have no control on the jar application I'm loading, so I can't modify the log4j properties file in it (the file is provided to me as part of the build process, installed and loaded by my application). I understand the warning is harmless, but having a completely unrelated message on console should not be ignored. Is there any way to modify the log4j file this external jar uses at runtime?

Comment: Can you really not just make a Log4J config file? And it's not an unrelated message, and you *can* ignore it.

Comment: @Dan: Dave doesn't mean to change the log4j config file built into the jar. Just write your own in your project that uses said jar.

Comment: @DaveNewton:lol I know I can ignore it, I said I shouldn't. It is unrelated (at least to the end user).

Comment: @RyanStewart: Adding a new log4j config file to my app's classpath will take precedence over the one included in the external jar?

Comment: @Dan: First classpath entry always wins, and your own classes and files are almost always added to the classpath before libraries. If the jar file has a log4j.properties file, then create your own log4j.properties, and that one will be used.